# Better alternative to .getPixel()?

Tags: java, android, imaging

I am using this code in my **Android application** for converting a bitmap to pure black and white and it works:

```
public Bitmap ConvertToThreshold(Bitmap anythingBmap)
{
    int width = anythingBmap.getWidth();
    int height = anythingBmap.getHeight();
    int threshold = 120;
    for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<height;y++){

            int pixel = anythingBmap.getPixel(x, y);
            int gray = Color.red(pixel);
            if(gray < threshold){
                anythingBmap.setPixel(x, y, 0xFF000000);
            } else{
                anythingBmap.setPixel(x, y, 0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
        }
    }
    return anythingBmap;
}
```

The problem if the `.getPixel()` is extremely slow and hence this takes a long time to process. Is there a quicker approach to this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use public void `getPixels (int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)`.  This will return all the pixels at once.

Comment: How do you process individual pixels in this method?

Comment: Its a flattened matrix.  So the pixel at row n column m is at array position n*width+m

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to create a int[] buffer for pixel processing. After that, you just need to copy the array to a bitmap. The methods you need to use:

```
public void copyPixelsFromBuffer (Buffer src)
public void copyPixelsToBuffer (Buffer dst)
private static IntBuffer makeBuffer(int[] src, int n) {
         IntBuffer dst = IntBuffer.allocate(n);
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             dst.put(src[i]);
         }
         dst.rewind();
         return dst;
     }
```

Sample code:

```
final int N = mWidth * mHeight;
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
int[] data8888 = new int[N];
mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(makeBuffer(data8888, N));
```